# Trying to make a glorified aux splitter, but it won't work

Tags: low-pass, sound

I have a project due in a couple of months, and decided I want to make a aux splitter where you can control the volume of left and right on two inputs and get a single output, kind of like a mixing board.

Here is a quick schematic of the project:

[image]

When i connect it so a stereo headset if kind of works, but when i turn the potentiometers the sound is distorted. Tried connecting it to a boombox with implemented amplifier and it was only noise.

The potentiometers are 10k

I was wondering if the capacitors act as a low-pass filter and that in addition with the potentiometers will cut off different frequencies depending on what the potentiometers are turned to, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What are the 150 nF capacitors bringing to the party?

Comment: not quite sure to be honest, asked my professor and he said they would "smooth" the sound whatever that means..

Comment: Sounds like you need to consult a new prof.

Comment: yeah perhaps, would it work without the capacitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's get real: if we stipulate \$0\,\Omega\$ output impedance of our sources and put all the 10k pots in middle position, we have an output impedance of 1.34k.  If we combine that with a 150nF capacitor in the given manner, we get a lowpass with a corner frequency of \$\frac 1{2\pi \cdot 150\,\textrm{nF}\cdot 1.34 \,\textrm{k$\Omega$}} \approx 800\,\textrm{Hz}\$.  That's some serious smoothing here...  If the input sources have higher impedance, the corner frequency will go further down.

Capacitors for "smoothing" volume controls mainly make sense when the pots are DC-operated (namely, don't carry the actual signal but just a probing voltage).  If you want to "smooth" AC, you need capacities operating outside of the signal frequency range, so more like \$4.7\,\textrm{nF}\$.  But that would be comparatively pointless here.

Comment: Thank you! This was what i was worried about, but didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic had tiny parts and text that were too far apart. So I increased its size and cropped it.

The capacitors cut away many normal music and speech high audio frequencies.
If your professor listens to severely distorted acid rock with too much overdrive then the capacitors smooth away most of the distortion.
[image: somple]